# UpdateAsync(sobject) Method to update records in a (spawn) new transaction

Tags: apex, after-trigger, update, asynchronous, transaction

1. The documentation says that data on the external system.
2. Asynchronous operation is used to process\update these records

Query

1. Does this mean I can update Sobjects (custom and\or standard) using this method, will spawn\start a new transaction ?
   example, If Account trigger is updating the record, I want a bunch of other records (eg Contact) (large count which would hit the limits and break the account trigger transaction) to be updated and if I use  updateAsync(sobjects) and pass the large count of Contact objects in the parameter, then it will create a new transaction for later object and the account's transaction will not be affected ?

Please ask me questions if you feel some confusion in the query :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The async methods (e.g. `updateAsync`) are only for [External Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_external_objects.htm). You can identify these objects because they will have a different suffix. Custom objects end with `__c`, such as `My_Object__c`, while an External Object ends with `__x`, as in `My_External_Object__x`. External Objects live on a third-party system and are updated via REST API calls from the Salesforce platform to the third-party service.